# mostrar un resultado en ajax en tiempo real

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

tengo este código y el problema que presento es que si escribo varias veces una palabra y la palabra esta disponible en la base de datos me muestra el resultado tantas veces como letras tenga la palabra.

Por ejemplo si busco "stack" y esta disponible apareceria
Stack cinco veces y lo ideal sería que lo mostrará una sola vez.

```
<section class="Search">
        <article class="Search-bar">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="Search-input" placeholder="Buscar hechizo, ej: Expelliarmus" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" id="busqueda">
        </article>
        <div id="resultados" class="Search-resultados"></div>

        <script>
            $('#busqueda').keyup(function(e){
                $("#resultados").text("");
                consulta = $("#busqueda").val();
                 $.ajax({
                 data: {'name': consulta},
                 url: '/buscar/',
                 type: 'get',
                 success : function(data) {                     
                        for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                            if((i % 2)==0)
                                $("#resultados").append("<a class=\"Search-resultados--item \" href=/"+data[i].slug+">"+data[i].name+"</a>");
                            else
                                $("#resultados").append("<a class=\"Search-resultados--item Search-resultados--info\" href=/"+data[i].slug+">"+data[i].name+"</a>");
                        }
                        if(consulta == ""){$("#resultados").text("");}
                 },
                 error : function(message) {
                         $("#resultados").text("");
                      }
                 });
            });
        </script>
    </section>
```

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme con esto se lo agradecería. Saludos!

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema o qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: Ya he editado, @Shaz sorry, mandé sin querer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo hemos arreglado. Por si a alguien le sirve, hemos puesto lo siguiente:

```
$("#resultados").text("");
```

justo antes del `for`

Comment: ¿Hemos arreglado? Curioso, no eres la misma persona que pregunta.

Comment: @Shaz yo era el que tenia la duda para ver si podiamos resolver el asunto xD

Comment: Por eso dije hemos en lugar de he  xD No encontrábamos el error y luego de que lo arregláramos me pasé por acá xD